# Why vertical scrollbar doesn't work in Firefox and IE and just work in Chrome?

Tags: css, browser, scrollbar

I have a div like this to show my contents:

```
<div id="contents"> ... </div>
```

And these codes in its css file:

```
#contents {
   padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
   overflow:auto;
   overflow-x:hidden;
   overflow-y:scroll;
   height:93%;
}
```

In some pages, I have lots of codes inside this div. But just in Google Chrome vertical scrollbar appears and I can use it. But in Firefox and IE, I can see just its place. There is not anything to click and drag for navigating contents from top to down.

I found out that the problem is `height` in css codes. Whenever I set it with `px` everything works fine. But I need to use it with `%`, because of my design style.

What sould I have to do?

*(Chrome 15, Firefox 6.0.2, IE 8)*

Comment: delete the overflow properties....you don't need them....Browsers automatically does the adjustment work

Comment: Could we possibly see more of the HTML structure? Is `#contents` within another container? Why 93%? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @rebz, yes it is. I have a 2-columns template. But I have to prevent scroll whole of the page. I must show the scrollbar just inside #contents. As there is a fixed footer div at the bottom of the page, I used 93% ...